# Wait for API call inside another API call when de second depends on the first?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, fetch, use-effect

I need to fetch data from two different endpoints, but the second endpoint depends on the result of the first one.

I'm working with react using typescript and I got a component that accepts an array of objects as parameter

```
function x() {
  const info: Array < Object > = [];
  const [xInfo, setxInfo] = useState(new Array < object > ());

  useEffect(() => {
      const firstRequest =
        fetch(firstUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(res => Object.keys(res.message).map(function(key) {
          constSecondRequest =
            fetch(`https://foo/api/${key}/image/`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(img => info.push({
              name: key,
              img: img.message
            }))
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
            .finally(
              //setstate
            )
        }))
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
        },
        [])
    return ( 
      <List info = { info } />
    }
  }
```

First API structure:

```
{
  "message": {
    "what I need": [],
    "what I need": [],
    "what I need": [
      useless info, useless info,
    ],
  }
}
```

second API structure

```
{
  "message": "link of image I need",
  "status": "success"
}
```

**I can't use classes**

I've already tried:
   -setting the state on the .finally of the 2nd request
   -remove the push, return just the object and use Promise.all

How can I wait for the second request finish before I pass the array to the List component?

Comment: You should be using state, and set state inside the second call's `.then`. Also, you might find `async`/`await` syntax to be easier to work with.

Comment: The value returned at the end of the function will be undefined because the return will fire before the promises are resolved. Instead of returning an html element, set the value of the element in the `finally` block.

Comment: You need to `return` those `secondRequest` promises and use `Promise.all` on them so that you properly chain them

Comment: Thanks everyone. The solution propose by @Bergi worked better in this specific case